# Cherry-picking merge commits

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I've got this scenario:

```
  sprint branch  - - - --30------60----- - - - ---150----
                                /     
  some fixes    - - ---57-----59    
                             /    
  some more fixes  - ------58
```

Now we realize we don't need the fixes merged in commit 60.

How can we revert them without removing everything else that was commited afterwards?

Comment: The diagram is a little confusing - what's the commit before 60? Do you want to not include 57-59 or just one of them? The git, you're always going back to some point in time. I would go back to 60~1 on sprint branch and cherrypick what I need OR interactive rebase and remove what the one commit I don't want.

Comment: @mjb Updated diagram with a commit pre-60. I don't want to include *anything* merged in 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git revert -m 1 60`. This will create a commit that undoes everything brought in from commit 60 (i.e. everything in 57, 58, 59, and all the other commits in the "some fixes" and "some more fixes" branch).

Note that if you want to bring in those fixes in the future, however, you won't be able to just merge commit 60 in again. Instead, you will have to "revert the revert," i.e. call `git revert` on the commit that the original `git revert` created.

Comment: what does the "1" mean in the arguments you're sending?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla - it means to treat the "sprint branch" as the one to compare to commit 60 for purposes of the reversion, as opposed to the branch that points to commit 59. This way it is commit 59 (and its ancestors) that is undone, as opposed to all the commits in "sprint branch" that are ancestors of 60.